# Getting Started with Android Fragments

Tags: android, fragment, tablet

I am trying to develop a tablet application that consists of a UI composed primarily of fragments.

I have no experience working with fragments and I am only a student so my programming knowledge is quite limited, but I'm getting there!

Basically I am just looking for advice from anyone who has experience using fragments and if anyone knows any good online resources or tutorials ( I tried google but did not find that many! ) I'd greatly appreciate if you would post them.

I guess one of the things I am finding it hard to understand is how you instantiate a fragment, do you need to create a Main Activity class and then create fragment objects and position them or what?...

Many thanks!

Comment: Also I know you "prefer questions that can be answered and not just discussed" but I really need some sort of direction as this application is very important to me.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/index.html#q=fragments

Comment: This website has great tutorials: http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html#fragments

Comment: Thank you both for those great links!

Comment: This user on YouTube has some good fragment tuts. They are for tablets but help you understand fragments a little easier. http://youtube.com/user/gatorman55

Comment: I actually saw some of his stuff last night, he explains things very clearly. I would highly recommend him to anyone looking to further their knowledge